# Paypal CreateBillingAgreement API Call not working with my api credentials

Tags: php, api, paypal, recurring-billing

I am using the master-sdk-php paypal api for making a billing agreement for reference transactions.

I got the token using the api SetExpressCheckout().Below is response :-

```
PayPal\PayPalAPI\SetExpressCheckoutResponseType Object
(
  [Token] => EC-1EG869789X969882G
  [Timestamp] => 2014-09-08T05:52:43Z
  [Ack] => Success
  [CorrelationID] => 84464deca9458
  [Errors] => 
  [Version] => 104.0
  [Build] => 12658619
)
```

but it is not working when I am calling the CreateBillingAgreement() api call.

I tested the code with demo api credentials and working fine. But it not working with my api credentials.

It is giving me Internal Error

Below is api call :-

```
// Include required library files.
require_once($main_path.'paypal_lib/includes/config.php');
require_once($main_path.'paypal_lib/autoload.php');

// Create PayPal object.
$PayPalConfig = array(
                'Sandbox' => $sandbox,
                'APIUsername' => 'bharat.maheshwari_api1.dotsquares.com',
                'APIPassword' => '********',
                'APISignature' => '*******', 
                'PrintHeaders' => $print_headers, 
                'LogResults' => $log_results,
                'LogPath' => $log_path,
                );


$PayPal = new angelleye\PayPal\PayPal($PayPalConfig);

// Pass data into class for processing with PayPal and load the response array into $PayPalResult
$Token = $_REQUEST['token'];
$PayPalResult = $PayPal->CreateBillingAgreement($_REQUEST['token']);

// Write the contents of the response array to the screen for demo purposes.
echo '<pre />';
print_r($PayPalResult);
```

I have used below api credentials for testing :-

```
  $PayPalConfig = array(
                'Sandbox' => $sandbox,
                'APIUsername' => 'jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com',
                'APIPassword' => 'WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F',
                'APISignature' => 'AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu-RWy', 
                'PrintHeaders' => $print_headers, 
                'LogResults' => $log_results,
                'LogPath' => $log_path,
                );
```

And code working fine but not working with my api credentials.I used my details with other adaptive payment api and working fine. It is generating token also with my details.

Response from paypal :-

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-09-08T04:54:02Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => ec2641e7483b6
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 112.0
    [BUILD] => 12658619
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10001
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    [ERRORS] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [L_ERRORCODE] => 10001
                [L_SHORTMESSAGE] => Internal Error
                [L_LONGMESSAGE] => Internal Error
                [L_SEVERITYCODE] => Error
            )

    )

[REQUESTDATA] => Array
    (
        [USER] => bharat.maheshwari_business_api1.dotsquares.com
        [PWD] => ******
        [VERSION] => 112.0
        [BUTTONSOURCE] => AngellEYE_PHPClass
        [SIGNATURE] => ******
        [METHOD] => CreateBillingAgreement
        [TOKEN] => EC-28P65999553574317
    )

    [RAWREQUEST] => USER=bharat.maheshwari_business_api1.dotsquares.com&PWD=******&VERSION=112.0&BUTTONSOURCE=AngellEYE_PHPClass&SIGNATURE=*******2&METHOD=CreateBillingAgreement&TOKEN=EC-28P65999553574317
    [RAWRESPONSE] => TIMESTAMP=2014%2d09%2d08T04%3a54%3a02Z&CORRELATIONID=ec2641e7483b6&ACK=Failure&VERSION=112%2e0&BUILD=12658619&L_ERRORCODE0=10001&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Internal%20Error&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Internal%20Error&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
)
```

Comment: So the section that you say is working looks like you set the API credentials directly in the $PayPalConfig array, but on the code that isn't working you're using PHP constants.  Are you sure those are populating the way you think they are?

Comment: no, its not issue with constants. I want to say that the api working with the credentials given in the api demo. But not working with credentials for my app. I an updating my question for removing the confusion of the constans.

Comment: Can you show me what you're getting from the output?  The entire dump of $PayPalResult?  I want to see the RAWREQUEST and RAWRESPONSE that come back in $PayPalResult. (but of course you can mask your api credentials again.)

Comment: You know what I think it might be, actually.  In order to use reference transactions with PayPal (billing agreements) you have to get that specifically enabled on your live account.  Have you done that?

Comment: I have updated my question. You can see the response now. I did nothing on live account. As I started it with a fresh account and application is still in production.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved the issue. It was due to my account was not enabled for reference transaction. It was enabled by paypal support team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been solved. It was due to my account was not enabled for reference transaction. It was enabled by paypal support team.

Comment: Had a feeling that was the problem.